# Disable scientific notation on axes using Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

How can you disable scientific output of numbers on an axis in bokeh?
For example, I want 400000 and not 4.00e+5

In mpl: `ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)`

Answer (score 25):

You can disable scientific notation with this:

```
fig = plt.figure(title='xxx', x_axis_type='datetime')
fig.left[0].formatter.use_scientific = False
```

Comment: The code above actually disables it on the vertical y-axis. If you want to disable scientific notation on the horizontal x-axis for a line plot, use: `fig.below[0].formatter.use_scientific = False`.

Comment: Code and my comment above works with latest version of Bokeh as of 2019-01-01 (v1.0.3).

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to turn off scientific notation from a logarithmic axis, and the above answers did not work for me.

I found this: [python bokeh plot how to format axis display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657448/python-bokeh-plot-how-to-format-axis-display)

In that spirit, this worked for me:

```
from bokeh.models import BasicTickFormatter

fig = plt.figure(title='xxx', x_axis_type='datetime',y_axis_type='log')
fig.yaxis.formatter = BasicTickFormatter(use_scientific=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

To disable the **scientific output** in **Bokeh**, use `use_scientific` attribute of the *formatter* you use.

You can find more information regarding `use_scientific` attribute here:

- a description of the attribute in the code of bokeh: [BasicTickFormatter
  class (line 28)](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/models/formatters.py#L28)
- [documentation of `use_scientific` attr](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models.html#bokeh.models.formatters.BasicTickFormatter.use_scientific)

**Example** (originaly comes from [Bokeh issues discussion](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1549)):

```
from bokeh.models import Axis
yaxis = bar.chart.plot.select(dict(type=Axis, layout="left"))[0]
yaxis.formatter.use_scientific = False
bar.chart.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that as of Bokeh v0.9.1, Marek's answer will no longer work due to changes in the interface for `Charts`. The following code ([from GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1549#issuecomment-125299409)) is a fully-functional example of how to turn off scientific notation in a high level chart.

```
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models import Axis
from bokeh.charts import Bar
data = {"y": [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], "z": [1, 5, 12, 4, 2]}
bar = Bar(data)
yaxis = bar.select(dict(type=Axis, layout="left"))[0]
yaxis.formatter.use_scientific = False
script, div = components(bar)
print(script)
print(div)
```

The key lines are:

```
yaxis = bar.select(dict(type=Axis, layout="left"))[0]
yaxis.formatter.use_scientific = False
```