# python bokeh plot how to format axis display

Tags: python, bokeh

the y axis ticks seem to be formatting numbers like 500000000 to 5.000e+8. Is there a way to control the display so that it displays as 500000000?

using python 2.7, bokeh 0.5.2

i m trying out the timeseries example at bokeh tutorials page

The tutorial plots 'Adj Close' against 'Date' but i'm plotting with 'Volume' against 'Date'

Comment: Here is the link to the code .. http://bokeh.pydata.org/tutorial/topical.html#timeseries

I m using Volume in place of Adj Close

Comment: got around my problem by formatting before putting the data in the ColumnDataSource. this way, the hover text format can be controlled. But I still haven't been able to format the axis displays..

Answer (score 22):

You can also use NumeralTickFormatter as used in the toy plot below.  The other possible values in place of '00' are listed [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.NumeralTickFormatter).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 90000000000, (10,1)), columns=['my_int'])
p = figure(plot_width=700, plot_height=280, y_range=[0,100000000000])
output_file("toy_plot_with_commas")

for index, record in df.iterrows():
    p.rect([index], [record['my_int']/2], 0.8, [record['my_int']], fill_color="red", line_color="black")

p.yaxis.formatter=NumeralTickFormatter(format="00")
show(p)
```

Answer (score 12):

You have to add the option `p.left[0].formatter.use_scientific = False` to your code. In the timeseries tutorial, it'd be:

```
p1 = figure(title="Stocks")
p1.line(
    AAPL['Date'],
    AAPL['Adj Close'],
    color='#A6CEE3',
    legend='AAPL',
)

p1.left[0].formatter.use_scientific = False # <---- This forces showing 500000000 instead of 5.000e+8 as you want

show(VBox(p1, p2))
```