# How to change tick label in pandas-bokeh plot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

I was trying to use pandas-bokeh library to make an interactive bar chart. Below is my dataframe that I want to plot.

My dataframe
[image]

After that,I plot it using this code

```
> df4.plot_bokeh(
>     kind='bar',
>     x='year', 
>     y=['Furniture','Office Supplies','Technology'],
>     yticks=np.arange(0,200000,10000)
>     )
```

interactive bar chart
[image]

As you can see, they yticks is using e+x. I want the yticks to be integers so the chart would be easier to be understood. Is there any way to do that in pandas-bokeh plot?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation of the library [there](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/styling.html). In docs, your problem has been
explained clearly. Also, you can use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657448/python-bokeh-plot-how-to-format-axis-display). Both sources used like this

```
p.xaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.0%")
p.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="$0.00")
```

Comment: In that case, the format value might be different. For this, you should use [there](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html)

Comment: i tried it on a plot drawn using .plot_bokeh() method (from pandas_bokeh library) and it didn't work.  But it did work when the plot is drawn using figure() from bokeh.plotting. i guess i'll use bokeh_plotting instead.

Thank you for the answer.